# How would I add 0.0.15.255. to 172.1.6.255.?

Tags: computer-networks

How would I add 0.0.15.255 to 172.1.6.255, talking about IPv4 networks here. I have done things like 192.168.1.15 plus 0.0.1.30 to be 192.168.2.45. but when it goes over the limit of 255, I just do not now how to do this... Help?

This is the what I am assigned to do:

I am given the block of adresses 172.16.0.0. and am told to design a scheme/ diagram of an adressing of the following given network, using basic subnetting:

1.HQ Lan (500 hosts)
2.West Lan(400 hosts)
3. East Lan (400 hosts)...
.... 
... 
..
15. WAN 8 (2 hosts)

So the assignment is done like $2^p\geq15 \implies p=4$
So, since the default subnet for our given adress is $/ 16 + /p= /20\implies 12$ bits are left for hosts.(meaning 12 $1's$ to add to an adress to get the broadcast..)$2^{12}-2 > 500,$(because of HQ Lan , with the most number of hosts..) therefore subnetting is possible.
Then it says that the IP of the subnetworks are as follows (with broadcast adresses.)

$$1. \text{HQ Lan:} \ \ 172.16.0.0. \ \  \text{ Broadcast adress:  } \ \  172.16.15.255. \\ 
2.\text{West Lan:} \ \ 172.16.16.0. \ \  \text{ Broadcast adress:  } \ \ 172.16.31.255. \\ 3.
\text{East Lan:} \ \ 172.16.32.0. \ \  \text{ Broadcast adress:  } \ \ 172.47.255.255. \\ ... \\ 15. \text{WAN 8:} \ \ 172.16.224.0. \ \  \text{ Broadcast adress:  } \ \ 172.16.239.255.$$

I can assume from this context one can deduct can deduct from what I mean by "add".
If I had the example: $$\text{Example LAN:172.1.6.255. } \text{ Subnetmask: ???}$$
I would have to add by $0.0.15.255. $

Comment: 1. What does this have to do with computer science? Looks like network engineering to me. 2. How do you get “Example LAN:172.1.6.255”? Why do you want to add something to it? Do you understand what a netmask is (if not, start by reading about that)?

Comment: You wouldn't. Adding IP addresses makes no more sense than adding street addresses or telephone numbers.

Comment: No one understands me !!

Comment: Please don't make edits that deface your question.

Comment: 0.0.15.255 is not a number of hosts, or a broadcast address either, and it has no apparent relationship with the IP addresses you've listed. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

You don't.  Adding IP addresses makes no sense.  It's like asking "How would I add an apple to a kiwi?"  (Sounds like a setup for some bad joke, I know.)  Not all things can be added.  There's no reason why you'd ever need to add two arbitrary IP adresses.

---

Based on the edited question, it appears that you want to design a scheme to assign IP addresses, and your idea was to do this by somehow adding IP addresses to each other.  Time to try a new idea.  There are ways to solve the design problem without trying to "add" IP addresses (which doesn't mean anything anyway).  In other words, you've got an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160917).  You might start by reading about netmasks, subnets, and local-area networks in your favorite networking textbook.

Comment: Basically, I am to assign IP adresses to subnetworks based on there needed demands host wise. I am told that the first subnetwork has this long 172.... adress and am to add this many hosts onto it. Then the next subnetwork would have to have an adress one above the broadcast adress of this previous one. Does that make sense ?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic, sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160917).  I can't understand what you're really trying to accomplish, but why don't you ask a new question with what you're really trying to accomplish?  Make sure to explain the goal (e.g., give an example), and show us what approaches you've considered and where you're stuck.

Comment: I will edit this one accordingly